# Android kotlin - return int for "parent" function

Tags: android, kotlin

This is the code

```
private fun like(id: Int): Int{

    val params = RequestParams()
    params.put("id", id)


    val client = AsyncHttpClient()
    client.post("https://www.ttt.com/ttt.php", params, object : JsonHttpResponseHandler()
    {
        override fun onSuccess(statusCode: Int, headers: Array<Header>?, response: JSONArray?)
        {
            return 1
        }
        override fun onFailure(statusCode: Int, headers: Array<Header>?, e: Throwable, response: JSONArray?)
        {
            return 0
        }
    })
}
```

As you can see I try to return either 1 or 0 for the parent function `like` after I get API responsebut the error is:

```
The integer literal does not conform to the expected type Unit
```

I can't find similar questions!
How can I do this?

Comment: You can't return something from an asynchronous callback. So your `like` function can't return anything about success or failure of the asynchronous call. Put whatever you want to do next directly in the callback code. Or you can use coroutines.

Comment: have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57330766/how-to-get-data-from-any-asynchronous-operation-in-android), as @Tenfour04 has pointed out, hopefully this can help you :)

Comment: So it's impossible? I can't do it directly in response because I need to return something to onBindViewHolder in recyclerview adapter

Comment: You can use the listener way to return value from async request

Comment: Yes, it is impossible. `onBindViewHolder` should not have to make HTTP requests to get the data for its views. If the data is not ready, make the associated text view blank or show a spinner. Do your HTTP requests separately and update the backing list of the Adapter once you have the data you need. Then call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`.

Comment: @Tenfour04 no the data is already set, I only need this function so the user can vote for the post he is currently viewing, I removed the code that isn't necessary for this question

Comment: I'll check out the callback stuff then thanks